# Using PIP3 to install Pyautogui package but still getting this error - No module named 'pyautogui' (Python)

Tags: python

I am using a windows system and I have no idea why after I use the command "pip3 install pyautogui" it installs successfully however when I click the play button in VS code it gives me an error in the terminal -

**ERROR**

```
import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

I am a pure beginner to Python so I have no idea what might be causing this issue. My code is below:

**CODE**

```
import pyautogui

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()

print(screenWidth)
print(screenHeight)
```

Any idea what I can do to solve this? I have checked similar questions but the answers were targeted more towards Linux users.

Comment: Try restarting your IDE and see if it works.

Comment: Yes I installed it from the terminal in VS Code and already restarted my IDE but it still did not work :(

Comment: Also make sure the python version you installed it into is the same as the one you are using to run the program.

Comment: My Python version is 3.10.9 , How do I check to see if it is the same one i am using to run the program? Sorry if this question might sound silly, I am a noob at Python

Comment: Type `py -3.10 -m pip freeze` in the terminal and see if pyautogui shows up.

Comment: "PyAutoGUI==0.9.53" This showed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251351/discussion-between-fractalism-and-hadi-zouhbi).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes pip can have problems with certain libraries.

to get around this, you should download the .whl or tar.gz file and install it directly from there.
this is the .tar.gz file for pyautogui: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/76/7a0ec1013bc3559b7438f6773cba05ffaec600b8989be2d621a144e39b50/PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar.gz
download it and put it in your project directory.
then, just pip install {THE FILE NAME}.
for me that fixed it.

Comment: keep in mind that you might need python wheel in order for this to work